# List of lists of lists how to make a map recursively

Tags: list-manipulation

```
 list = {ab, ad, {be, br, pb, {cd, cr, ce, {fo}, {gf, gh, gv, gg},  ne, {ks, kd, kl}, {sa, sx, sr, {sdr, svd, {ssfrt, styi}, {sfc, sfb, smaa}, ja}}}}, aw}
```

I would like to produce all this outputs with a `Fold` or `Nest` or so but it's over my level ...

```
tdl1 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[i]]], {i, Length[list[[i]]]}, list[[i]]],
    {i, Length[list]}
]
```

> {ab, ad, {3, 4}, aw}

```
tdl2 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, i]]]}, list[[3, i]]],
    {i, tdl1[[3, 2]]}
]
```

> {be, br, pb, {4, 8}}

```
tdl3 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, i]]]}, list[[3, 4, i]]], 
    {i, tdl2[[4, 2]]}
]
```

> {cd, cr, ce, {4, 1}, {5, 4}, ne, {7, 3}, {8, 4}}

```
tdl4 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 4, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 4, i]]]},  list[[3, 4, 4, i]]],
    {i, tdl3[[4, 2]]}
]
```

> {fo}

```
tdl5 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 5, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 5, i]]]},  list[[3, 4, 5, i]]],
    {i, tdl3[[5, 2]]}
]
```

> {gf, gh, gv, gg}

```
tdl6 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 7, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 7, i]]]},  list[[3, 4, 7, i]]],
    {i, tdl3[[7, 2]]}
]
```

> {ks, kd, kl}

```
tdl7 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 8, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 8, i]]]}, list[[3, 4, 8, i]]],
    {i, tdl3[[8, 2]]}
]
```

> {sa, sx, sr, {4, 5}}

```
tdl8 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, i]]]}, list[[3, 4, 8, 4, i]]],
    {i, tdl7[[4, 2]]}
]
```

> {sdr, svd, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, ja}

```
tdl9 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 3, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 3, i]]]}, list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 3, i]]],
    {i, tdl8[[3, 2]]}
]
```

> {ssfrt, styi}

```
 tdl10 = Table[
    If[ListQ[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 4, i]]], {i, Length[list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 4, i]]]}, list[[3, 4, 8, 4, 4, i]]],
    {i, tdl8[[4, 2]]}
]
```

> {sfc, sfb, smaa}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f0, tdl1, tdl2]
f0 = Replace[#, x_List :> Flatten[{Position[#, x], Length @ x}], 1] &;
```

You can use `f0` with [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
tdl1 = Extract[#, Sort@Position[#, _List], f0] &; 
tdl1 @ list // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\text{ab},\text{ad},\{3,4\},\text{aw}\} \\
>  \{\text{be},\text{br},\text{pb},\{4,8\}\} \\
>  \{\text{cd},\text{cr},\text{ce},\{4,1\},\{5,4\},\text{ne},\{7,3\},\{8,4\}\} \\
>  \{\text{fo}\} \\
>  \{\text{gf},\text{gh},\text{gv},\text{gg}\} \\
>  \{\text{ks},\text{kd},\text{kl}\} \\
>  \{\text{sa},\text{sx},\text{sr},\{4,5\}\} \\
>  \{\text{sdr},\text{svd},\{3,2\},\{4,3\},\text{ja}\} \\
>  \{\text{ssfrt},\text{styi}\} \\
>  \{\text{sfc},\text{sfb},\text{smaa}\} \\
> \end{array}$

or with`Table`:

```
tdl2 = Table[f0[#[[## & @@ i]]], {i, Sort@Position[#, _List]}] &;
tdl1@list == tdl2@list
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

Not very pretty but shorter:

```
foo // ClearAll
foo[list_List] := Module[{res}
, Sow @ MapIndexed[ If[ListQ @ #, Append[#2, Length @ #], #] &, list]
; foo /@ list; 
]

Column @ Reap[foo@list][[-1, 1]]
```

> ```
> {ab,ad,{3,4},aw}
> {be,br,pb,{4,8}}
> {cd,cr,ce,{4,1},{5,4},ne,{7,3},{8,4}}
> {fo}
> {gf,gh,gv,gg}
> {ks,kd,kl}
> {sa,sx,sr,{4,5}}
> {sdr,svd,{3,2},{4,3},ja}
> {ssfrt,styi}
> {sfc,sfb,smaa}
> ```

p.s. I don't like the fact that `foo` needs to map `list` twice but otherwise the order is wrong.

Comment: It's just the kind of solution I was looking for, that makes me study deeply your foo, Thank you, Eskerrik asko